# Insert row at position [0] of a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, insert

I have a frame like this one, where I insert a new row

```
import pandas as pd

s1 = pd.Series([5, 6, 7])
s2 = pd.Series([11, 12, 13])
s3 = pd.Series([22, 23, 24])

index_lst = ['StockA','StockB','StockC']

df = pd.DataFrame([list(s1), list(s2), list(s3)],  columns =  ["A", "B", "C"], index = index_lst)
insert_line = pd.DataFrame({'A' : 99, 'C' : 98}, index = ['NewStock'])
df2 = pd.concat([df.ix[0:], insert_line])
```

which gives me this

```
           A     B   C     
StockA     5  6.00   7  
StockB    11 12.00  13 
StockC    22 23.00  24 
NewStock  11   nan  22
```

How can I get my 'NewStock' entry to be inserted at row 0? I want this order

```
           A     B   C     
NewStock  11   nan  22   
StockA     5  6.00   7  
StockB    11 12.00  13 
StockC    22 23.00  24
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `pd.concat()` if they're both dataframes.

So maybe something like this?

```
import pandas as pd

s1 = pd.Series([5, 6, 7])
s2 = pd.Series([11, 12, 13])
s3 = pd.Series([22, 23, 24])

index_lst = ['StockA','StockB','StockC']

df = pd.DataFrame([list(s1), list(s2), list(s3)],  columns =  ["A", "B", "C"], index = index_lst)
insert_line = pd.DataFrame({'A' : 99, 'C' : 98}, index = ['NewStock'])


df = pd.concat([insert_line, df])
```